# Idea of a continuous Gear system in Cars

Tags: gears, car

**Background**

I randomly had this idea and i was wondoring if could it be a better alternate technology than what we use in cars now, but as i have little knowledge in the enginnering field(i'm a physics post graduate student) i had to ask this question here. I had this idea when i was learning transistors in which for a particular fixed $V_{be}$ voltage (between base and emitter in common emitter configuration) $I_c$ increases with increasing $V_{ce}$,but it has a maximum value limit, to increase the limit $V_{be}$ is increased thus the analogy being $V_{be}$ acts like a gear and $V_{ce}$ is the accelerator while $I_c$ is the speed.

**The Idea**

We have descrete gear system in cars now which changes like 1>2>3>4>5. But Like i mentioned in transistor analogy $V_{be}$ is continuos and can be changed infinitesimally, cant we have the same system in gears used in cars, i.e a *Continuous Gear*

**Advantage-**

Well i can't think of any significant advantage in the ease of driving but it will be pretty fun.

**Question**

Is this idea even possible? Or we already have something like this in automatic cars?If this idea is somehow possible will it help in ease of driving a car so that it becomes a piece of cake?

Comment: It exists - check out the Daf variomatic.

Comment: There is a marginal advantage, when comparing vs an automatic transmission at least. Slight delays of shifting during steady acceleration are eliminated. When you floor it, the software maintains something like 5k or 6k RPM until you let up the pedal. And at highway speeds, the RPM's end up a little lower, too. In general, the software has a bit more freedom to pick an optimal point on the engine's torque curve, so there's a small (low single digit %) net fuel efficiency gain from that. Future is electric drive though, which is fine with the engine running at just a few fixed operating points.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Continuously Variable Transmissions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuously_variable_transmission) are a thing, and often found in things like snow mobiles and other light vehicles.

They are not as common in heavy vehicles because they don't handle high torque very well, because they tend to rely on friction of smooth surfaces to transfer power rather than interlocking gears.

For maintenance you need to account for the uneven wear induced in in the friction surfaces which need to be rather large and fairly precise.

Comment: You find these in almost all Nissans, very common in cars these days.  Hybrid vehicles have a version that works electrically.

Comment: Just a note, snowmobile transmissions and similar applications use friction on the sides of the belt, but contemporary CVT systems "push" power transfer modules in a linear manner in line with the belt that guides them. The push aspect is not explicitly stated in the video: https://youtu.be/xHWqlfDZnmQ?si=cMH3a9UTwC_9m3Yy&t=87 but it was in an article in a long past Car and Driver magazine. The video suggests that up to 300 hp / 223 kw can be applied.

Comment: Subarus also have CVTs although they mimic fixed gears in some instances.